# Display child page content of a specific parent on home page

Tags: php, loop, pages, child-pages

This has been bugging the hell out of me, it should be so simple!

I have a list of child pages under the parent called 'Our Homes'. The sitemap structure is as follows:

- Home
- Our Homes

  - home 1
  - home 2
  - home 3

For each home I want to display the following:

- Title
- Content snippet
- Image
- Map
- Link to the child page for that home

How do I loop through each child page under 'Our Homes' and display the specified content above from each on the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this sounds like a good use-case for a custom post type for homes, but, in any case, this is the basic concept you'd need to follow to get this working as you've got it set up now.

```
<?php
// Set up the objects needed
$homes_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $homes_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));

// Get the page as an Object
$our_homes =  get_page_by_title('Our Homes');

// Filter through all pages and find Our Homes' children
$home_children = get_page_children( $our_homes->ID, $all_wp_pages );

// echo what we get back from WP to the browser
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $home_children, true ) . '</pre>';
?>
```

That will print the post objects, then you can pick and choose which elements (like title, etc.) that you want to echo out

Comment: You're absolutely right and now i'm kicking myself.